# How can I code for an anticontrol U1 gate in qiskit? There are references for anticontrol X but no U gate

Tags: physics, quantum-computing, qiskit, firefox-quantum

Some of them use https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/3b3536bcdb83124d49723dd205573f169c82ea9c/qiskit/circuit/add_control.py#L24 this code to implement the anticontrol X gate

Answer (score 0):

`U1Gate` is being replaced by `PhaseGate` (aka `p`). If you still want to use `u1`, replace the `import PhaseGate` in this example by `import U1Gate as PhaseGate`:

```py
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import PhaseGate
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.append(PhaseGate(3.14159).control(1, ctrl_state="0"), [0, 1])
print(circuit)
```

```
q_0: ─o─────
      │P(π) 
q_1: ─■─────
```

The method `control` takes the amount of qubits to control on (in this example, 1) and the `ctrl_state`. In this case, an anticontrol (aka open control) applies phase rotation on `q_1` if the `q_0 == 0`.